# how to retrieve route params when the angular 2 app is being called in an iframe

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, angular2-routing

My angular2 app is used in another application via an iframe. How would I retrieve the route params sent in the url/call from iframe to my angular2 app component? the regular approach of retrieving form  ActivatedRoute/ActivatedRouteSnapshot doesnt seem to work or am I doing anything wrong? Below is the sample code that i have in my resolver. not sure why my query params are undefined.

```html
@Injectable() 
export class AuthenticationResolver implements Resolve<Response> {

      constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
                 ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
           
        console.log(route.queryParams["user_id"]); // value is undefined
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.queryParams["user_id"]); // undefined too

        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set("id", route.queryParams['user_id']);
      
        return this.http.get("someUrl", { search: params });
              
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNn0v.jpg)

Comment: How does your URL looks like? It is possible that you have set route `params` and are looking for `queryParams`. There is a difference between two. Did you try logging out `route.params["user_id"]` .